# Google Maps Api Fusiontableslayer rendering bug on zoom under iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm experiencing this strange (and almost undocumented a.f.a.i.k) bug when zooming in a map that takes his geometry from a fusion tables to which some (dynamic) style are applied.

It seems it's only a tablet problem (map renders well in every desktop browser).

Here can be found an unlabeled demo project:

http://www.mmh-tech.com/maptest/

this is a link to a zipped folder with all the needed files:

http://www.mmh-tech.com/maptest/source.zip

Thanks in advance for any help!